# Can we use random variables in \polylongdiv

Tags: pgfmath, polynom

I would like to randomly generate polynomials before using \polylongdiv for long division. I tried the code below to make one of the coefficients of the divisor random but the compilation takes forever (it does not stop nor shows error).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetseed{5}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\coeffa{random(1,10)}
\polylongdiv{x^4-3x^3-5x^2+x-4}{x-\coeffa}
\end{document}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: You need to expand `\coeffa` used in 2nd arg of `\polylongdiv`. For example use `\expandafter\polylongdiv\expanded{{x^4-3x^3-5x^2+x-4}{x-\coeffa}}`.

Comment: it works! thank you @muzimuzhiZ